# What is the meaning of: ValueError: shapes (200,200) and (199,) not aligned: 200 (dim 1) != 199 (dim 0)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to simulate an option pricing scheme by defining functions (Black-Scholes and Crank-Nicolson) and comparing them. The implementation of the Crank-Nicolson scheme with boundary conditions is as follows (I include the full code for replication):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bs_call(S, K, r, sigma, T):
    d1 = (np.log(S/K) + (r + 0.5*sigma**2)*T) / (sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - sigma*np.sqrt(T)
    return S*norm.cdf(d1) - K*np.exp(-r*T)*norm.cdf(d2)

def crank_nicolson(S0, K, r, sigma, T, Smin, Smax, M, N):
    # Initialization
    dt = T/N
    ds = (Smax - Smin)/M
    S = np.linspace(Smin, Smax, M+1)
    tau = np.linspace(0, T, N+1)
    V = np.zeros((M+1, N+1))

    # Boundary conditions
    V[:, 0] = np.maximum(S-K, 0)
    V[0, :] = 0
    V[-1, :] = Smax-K*np.exp(-r*tau)

    # Tridiagonal matrix for the implicit step
    alpha = 0.25*dt*(sigma**2*S**2/ds**2 - r*S/ds)
    beta = -dt*0.5*(sigma**2*S**2/ds**2 + r)
    gamma = 0.25*dt*(sigma**2*S**2/ds**2 + r*S/ds)
    A = np.diag(alpha[2:], -1) + np.diag(1+beta[1:]) + np.diag(gamma[:-2], 1)
    B = np.diag(-alpha[2:], -1) + np.diag(1-beta[1:]) + np.diag(-gamma[:-2], 1)

    # Time loop
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        b = np.dot(B, V[1:-1, n-1])
        b[0] -= alpha[1]*V[0, n]
        b[-1] -= gamma[-2]*V[-1, n]
        V[1:-1, n] = np.linalg.solve(A, b)

    # Interpolation for S0
    i = int(round((S0-Smin)/ds))
    if i == M+1:
       i = M
    elif i == 0:
       i = 1
    a = (V[i+1, -1]-V[i, -1])/ds
    b = (V[i+1, -1]-2*V[i, -1]+V[i-1, -1])/ds**2
    return V[i, -1] + a*(S0-S[i]) + 0.5*b*(S0-S[i])**2
```

Up to here, so far so good. Afterwards, I run an example as follows (full code also included for replication):

```
# Example usage
S0 = 100
K = 100
r = 0.05
sigma = 0.2
T = 1
Smin = 0
Smax = 200
M = 200
N = 1000

option_price = crank_nicolson(S0, K, r, sigma, T, Smin, Smax, M, N)
```

However, I got an error here with the following message:

```
ValueError: shapes (200,200) and (199,) not aligned: 200 (dim 1) != 199 (dim 0)
```

and I do not know if it comes from the function definition (first part) or from the parameters definition (second script) and how can be solved.

Comment: That's not ALL of the error message, is it?  It looks like an message generated by a `np.dot` or `np.matmul/@`, i.e. matrix multiplication (which is documented).  Your task, based on the full message, is to identify which of your arrays have the wrong shapes.  You should know, or be able to display, the shape of all the `crank_nicolson` arguments.

Comment: I should know but I'm not sure. The problem seems to be in the value given to M and probably from the line `V = np.zeros((M+1, N+1))` or the line `S = np.linspace(Smin, Smax, M+1)` but not sure. The interpolation subroutine also uses the `M` parameter. I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Please, indent your code (pretty important in python). We can't reproduce it as is.

Comment: Indented. Sorry for the wrong format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused since `B.shape[1]` is `M`, whereas `V[1:-1, n-1].shape[0]` is `M-1`, which do not match, thus I'd guess the error is due to the function definition.

Changing

```
A = np.diag(alpha[2:], -1) + np.diag(1+beta[1:]) + np.diag(gamma[:-2], 1)
B = np.diag(-alpha[2:], -1) + np.diag(1-beta[1:]) + np.diag(-gamma[:-2], 1)
```

to

```
A = np.diag(-alpha[2:M], -1) + np.diag(1-beta[1:M]) + np.diag(-gamma[1:M-1], 1)
B = np.diag(alpha[2:M], -1) + np.diag(1+beta[1:M]) + np.diag(gamma[1:M-1], 1)
```

(heavily "inspired" by [this](https://hamedhelali.github.io/blog-post/FDM-European-option-pricing/) very similar implementation) gets rid of the error message and running

```
cn_price = crank_nicolson(S0, K, r, sigma, T, Smin, Smax, M, N)
bs_price = bs_call(S0, K, r, sigma, T)
print(cn_price, bs_price)
```

(with otherwise unchanged code) prints

```
10.3201002605872 10.450583572185565
```

Note that I am not familiar with the Crank-Nicolson method and can therefore only hope that the proximity of those values indicates a fix (i.e. correct adjustment) indeed, as opposed to a mere ridding of the error message.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Nevertheless, when plotting: ```plt.plot(S, bs_price, label='Exact', linewidth=2)``` I suspected that the following error would appear: ```ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (201,) and (1,)```and it happened.